# html2pdf not working with reactjs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

We are using [this](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) package with ReactJS. This is working as per expectation in all browsers except Firefox. When the user interacts to download the PDF, Firefox hangs completely, and show attached message.Memory usage looks fine.

Screenshot of Browser Message:
[image: Screenshot of Browser Message]

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying dynamic import by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am lazy loading through dynamic imports.

Comment: Trying removing that and use normal import.

Answer (score 0):

As according to me, If I understood your question, it seems like its a module issue that you are using, because it's an open issue not Fixed yet.
(description link:https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/issues/45 )

You can use some other popular library like react-pdf, PDFKit, pdfshift.

Hopefully, this can solve your issue.